# Evaluate passed value using .filter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a method that takes a language abbreviation and matches it using a `.constant` dictionary, and returns the matching language name.

How can I do an evaluation with `.filter` to check whether the passed isoCode/language abbreviation exists?

**Here is my method:**

```
angular.module('portalDashboardApp')

  .service('ISOtoLanguageService', ['Languages', function(Languages) {

    this.returnLanguage = function(isoCode) {

      var categoryObject = Languages.filter(function ( categoryObject ) {
        return categoryObject.code === isoCode;
      })[0];

      return categoryObject.name;

    };

  }]);
```

**Here is the method with some error catching I have tried:**

```
angular.module('portalDashboardApp')

  .service('ISOtoLanguageService', ['Languages', function(Languages) {

    this.returnLanguage = function(isoCode) {

        var categoryObject = Languages.filter(function (categoryObject) {
            if (isoCode != null || isoCode != undefined) {
                return categoryObject.code === isoCode;
            }
            else {
                return categoryObject.code === 'und';
            }        
      })[0];

      if (categoryObject.name != undefined || categoryObject.name != null) {
          return categoryObject.name;
      }
      else {
          return "undefined";
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Thank you!

Comment: `Languages` is your service-dictionary or any external?

Comment: off-topic: in JavaScript "isoCode != undefined" and "isoCode != null" both do the exact same. So you're safe to drop one of them. This only works with != and not with !==

Comment: @Antonio it is an internal .constant dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you organize your data at `Languages`in an object or map, it'll be much faster and simpler when you fetch your translation by an abbreviation. A short example:

```
angular.module('portalDashboardApp')
  .factory('Languages', function(){
    var dictionary = {
      ISO: {name: 'International Organization for Standardization'}
    };
    return {
       get: function(abbr){
           return dict[abbr];
       }
    };
  }).service('ISOtoLanguageService', ['Languages', function(Languages) {
    this.returnLanguage = function(isoCode) {
       if(!isoCode) {
         return "Answer for empty isoCode";
       }
       var categoryObject = Languages.get(isoCode);
       return (categoryObject || {}).name || "I don't know this abbr";
  };

}]);
```

I'm not sure that this JS works without any syntax error (I've not try to launch it) but idea is that you don't need array and `filter` on big dictionaries and you are able to get any abbreviation from dict with O(1) complexity even with huge dictionary.

If you don't want to have a refactoring with your code you can do something like  this:

```
angular.module('portalDashboardApp')

  .service('ISOtoLanguageService', ['Languages', function(Languages) {

    this.returnLanguage = function(isoCode) {
        if (!isoCode) {
            return;
        }

        var resultAbbrs = Languages.filter(function (categoryObject) {
            return categoryObject.code === isoCode;
        });

        if (resultAbbrs.length > 0) {
            return resultAbbrs[0].name;
        }
    };
  }]);
```

In this case if `isoCode` is null, undefined or empty string or this key is not found in dictionary `return undefined` will be by default. Outside you should check a result of this function with `if (result === undefined) ...`

I hope it helped you)

Comment: Thank you for the input and feedback and great suggestion. But is there perhaps a way for me to do an evaluation on `.filter` with my code as is?

Comment: @onmyway I changed my answer, try it please

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. Also, just an FYI; although I have my language dictionary set up as .constant dictionary, and I use the method as shown above, to export a file of 1000 records to csv, doing the language conversion and other stuff, takes a fraction of a second.